# Alternative to ToString() for an index search ( C# converted to SQL )

Tags: c#, sql, sitecore, iqueryable

I currently have the following in a Sitecore ( Sitecore 8 Update 2 ) project:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> queryCalls = index.CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(item =>
                 item.TemplateName == callTemplateName &&
                 item.Path.StartsWith(callStartingPath) && 
                 item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name &&
                 item.Fields["appliedthemes"].ToString().Contains(themeID))
```

This should give me all items under a certain path with a certain templatename in a certain language( works fine ).
The last line makes sure only the items with a specific tag are returned.

However it seems i can not use the ToString() method in this last statement as this can not be converted to SQL. But i'm unable to find an other way to write this.

EDIT:

the error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The method 'ToString' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Object
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The method 'ToString' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Object
```

Comment: wt is the error u are getting?

Comment: What datatype does item.Fields["appliedThemes"] return?

Comment: Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field

Comment: try item.Fields["appliedthemes"].Value.ToString()

Comment: Can you be explicit as to how app

Answer (score 4):

This isn't LINQ to SQL therefore the query is not converted to SQL, it is translated into a query for your underlying search provider (Lucene, Solr, Coveo, etc.).

As you've found, invoking `.ToString()` is not supported, but it is also not needed. You can call the indexer and get the field value directly:

```cs
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext()) {
    IQueryable<SearchResultItem> queryCalls = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(item =>
             item.TemplateName == callTemplateName &&
             item.Path.StartsWith(callStartingPath) && 
             item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name &&
             item["appliedthemes"].Contains(themeID))
}
```

The `Item` item class has an indexer that will return the string value of the field. It also has the benefit of returning an empty string if the field doesn't exist on the item (whereas calling `item.Fields["Field Name"].Value` can result in a NullReference exception if the field doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `appliedthemes` field is a single-line, multi-line, or rich-text field, I would suggest that you create your own class that inherits from `SearchResultItem`.

```
public class TaggedItem : SearchResultItem 
{
    [IndexField("appliedthemes")]
    public string AppliedThemes { get; set; }
}
```

If your field happens to be a multi-valued field, you can use an `IEnumerable<T>` property to represent the values. Either way, now that you have defined your own class, you can use it as follows:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var queryCalls = context.GetQueryable<TaggedItem>()
            .Where(item => item.TemplateName == callTemplateName)
            .Where(item => item.Path.StartsWith(callStartingPath))
            .Where(item => item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name)
            .Where(item => item.AppliedThemes.Contains(themeID));

    //...

}
```